# Average treatment effect from matrix of individual posterior distributions

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, posterior, treatment-effect, bart

I'm trying to estimate the average treatment effect of an intervention using the potential outcomes framework in a classification problem. The analysis uses machine learning to learn $\hat{y} = f(Y, X, Z)$ with Y being a categorical outcome, X being a dichotomic treatment variable and Z being other covariates.

By using a BART model, I get for each observation the posteriors $p_{0_{ij}} = P(\hat{y} = 1_{do:X = 0}|Z)$ and $p_{1_{ij}} = P(\hat{y} = 1_{do:X = 1}|Z)$, forming two matrices ($p_0$ and $p_1$) with $i$ rows for each observation and $j$ column for each posterior sample.
My goal is to compute the posterior of the relative risk between the groups $X = 1$ vs $X = 0$.

I'd like to know if the following *approach* is correct:

- take the log of the ratio of $p_1$ over $p_0$ to get the $ i\times j$ log-RR matrix;
- take the column average to get a $j$-long vector representing the posterior distribution of log-RR;
- exponentiate again to get the posterior distribution of RR.

I noticed that the width of this posterior is quite wide, so I was wondering if I am missing something or it is something to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to estimate the marginal risk ratio after BART is the following:

1. Under each treatment level, compute the posterior of the marginal risks by averaging across the rows (i.e., compute the column means to get a vector of marginal risks, which is the posterior for the marginal risk under each treatment level).
2. Divide each member of the vector for $X=1$ by the corresponding member of the vector for $X=0$. This new vector is the posterior for the risk ratio.

If you want predicted individual risk ratios, you can just divide the $p_1$ matrix by the $p_0$ matrix. Each row is the posterior of the predicted individual risk ratio for each unit. Note that the average of the predicted individual risk ratios for each draw of the posterior is not equal to the marginal risk ratio because the risk ratio is not collapsible  (and taking the log doesn't make it so). You don't need to take logs because you estimated the risks directly, and the risk ratio is just a function of the risks.

Comment: Dear Noah, thank you for the reply. Can you elaborate more on the problem of collapsibility? I used https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236588890_Bayesian_Nonparametric_Modeling_for_Causal_Inference (pag 9) and https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/76348572.pdf (pag 5) and they seem to take the average of the individual level effect (I used the log since I was not confortable with the mean of a RR). Do you suggest to take the ratio of counterfactual sample averages instead or I misunderstood?

Comment: They can take the average of the individual-level effects because the effect measure they used is the risk difference, which is collapsible, meaning the marginal risk difference is equal to the average of the individual risk differences. This is not true for risk ratios so you can't apply those formulas. The marginal risk ratio is the ratio of the marginal risks, which are the average risk across the sample under each treatment. So yes, that is what I am suggesting. Compute the counterfactual averages (i.e., marginal risks), then take the ratio of those to get the marginal risk ratio.

Comment: Thank you. is what you say the RR(-) defined here https://ete-online.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12982-018-0083-9 ? 
Or can you point me to a relevant reference, I cannot risk to misunderstand it.
Another question, I thought I was estimating the conditional ATE, not the marginal ATE, does this count?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the causal RR(-) as defined in that paper, which I had not come across but quite liked. The method I described was described in the last paragraph of that paper (but performed within each draw of the posterior to get a posterior distribution of RR(-)).

Comment: The conditional ATE (CATE) is the ATE for each individual. That is what I described in the last paragraph of my answer. You can get a CATE(RR(-)) for each individual by just dividing the predicted risks under the two treatments. There is no single CATE; there is a CATE for each individual (or for any arbitrary combination of predictor values, which is how individuals are identified).

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question if I may: what is then the difference between the ITE and the CATE?

Comment: For the CATE, you can choose the conditioning variables, and it doesn't have to be all of them. So a CATE conditioning on just 2 out of 5 effect modifiers is still a CATE. An ITE necessarily conditions on all effect modifiers. ITEs are basically impossible to estimate. CATEs get closer to them.